# "virtual" switch statement in C#?

Tags: c#, inheritance, switch-statement

I'm writing a class that reads a text file and creates some data structures based on it.  I have no control over the file format, but it is consistent and I have many examples.  Every now and then, I encounter a page header.  I pull out a string from the header, and that informs what I do with the rest of the page.  I use a switch statement like this:

```
private void ReadPage(headerKey)
{
    switch (headerKey)
    {
        case "a header": DoThis(headerKey); return;
        case "another header": DoThat(headerKey, "A"); return;
        case "header 3": DoThat(headerKey, "B"); return;
        // 10-20 more cases
    }
}
```

It works well, but now I have made this class abstract and created two subclasses.  There are a few cases in the switch statement that apply to both subclasses, but each has some unique cases.  I'm trying to code this in a way that still looks pretty.  I could use a dictionary with a virtual method that populates it, but the syntax for that is so ugly, and I have the overhead of creating a dictionary for each instance of the class.

```
private readonly Dictionary<string, Action<string>> headerKeyCases();

private A()
{
    headerKeyCases = new Dictionary<string, Action<string>>(GetVariableGridParsersByName);
}

protected virtual IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, Action<string>>> GetVariableGridParsersByName()
{
    yield return new KeyValuePair<string, Action<string>>("a header", headerKey=> DoThis(headerKey));
    yield return new KeyValuePair<string, Action<string>>("another header", headerKey=> DoThat(headerKey, "A"));
    yield return new KeyValuePair<string, Action<string>>("header 3", headerKey=> DoThat(headerKey, "B"));
    // 10-20 more cases
}
```

Is there a cleaner way to do this, or am I just being too picky?

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ is more appropriate place for code review

Comment: You are being too picky. Although `new KeyValuePair<string, Action<string>>` could be shortened to `SomeUtilityMethod` and `headerKey` shortened to `k`.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about improving working code, and therefore is more suitable for [codereview.se].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private readonly Dictionary<string, Action<string>> headerKeyCases;

private A()
{
    headerKeyCases = GetVariableGridParsersByName();

    // Add another
    headerKeyCases["another case"] = headerKey => DoSomething(headerKey, "C");
}

protected virtual void GetVariableGridParsersByName()
{
    return new Dictionary<string, Action<string>>({
        { "a header", DoThis },
        { "another header", headerKey => DoThat(headerKey, "A") }
        // etc.
    });
}
```

Comment: I guess the base would look like this?

    protected override void GetVariableGridParsersByName()
    {
        Dictionary<string, Action<string>> dict = base.GetVariableGridParsersByName();
        dict.Add("a header", DoThis);
        dict.Add("another header", headerKey => DoThat(headerKey, "A"));
        // etc.
        });
    }

Comment: @hypehuman I don't understand your question there... My code is idea of cleaner code, no `new KeyValuePair<string, Action<string>>`, no yield return, etc.

Comment: Thanks, it does look a lot better that way.  I was just showing how I think the method should be overridden in the child class, but it seems like it works :)  It would just call the base implementation and call .Add to put more cases into the dictionary.